# primefaces tristatecheckbox label left side

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tri-state-logic

How do I place the itemLabel for the primefaces TriStateCheckbox on the left side of the checkbox instead of the default right position.

[image]

```
<p:triStateCheckbox value="#{handler.readyFlag}" 
        itemLabel="#{labels.aktiv}"
        converter="triStateConverter">
                <p:ajax event="change" update="workflowEventTbl"
                        listener="#{handler.createDataModel}"
                        partialSubmit="true"/>
</p:triStateCheckbox>
```

Workaround:
I can put a label in front of it, but then it is not "clickable" like the label on the TriStateCehckbox

```
<h:outputText value="#{labels.aktiv}"/>
<p:triStateCheckbox value="#{handler.readyFlag}"
    converter="triStateConverter">
        <p:ajax event="change" update="workflowEventTbl"
                listener="#{handler.createDataModel}"
                partialSubmit="true"/>
</p:triStateCheckbox>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create CSS rule to float to label to the left. For example:

```
html .ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-label {
  float: left;
}
```

Of course you could add a style class to your `p:triStateCheckbox` and create a more specific rule.

See also:

- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)